# Slowing the other part when use open mp

Tags: visual-studio-2012, parallel-processing, openmp

I am implementing the simple "for clause" using open mp in visual studio 2012.
This implementation file is .cu file to be compiled by nvcc.
When using omp, the "for clause" gets fast, but other parts get slow.
I can't find the answer although surfing the many related questions.
Code follows.

```
void Test()
{
unsigned char* pbDest = (unsigned char*)malloc(1000000);
unsigned char* pbSrc = (unsigned char*)malloc(3000000);
#pragma omp parallel for shared(pbDest, pbSrc)
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i ++)
    {
        pbDest[i] = (unsigned char)((299 * pbSrc[3 * i] + 587 * pbSrc[3 * i + 1] + 114 * pbSrc[3 * i + 2]) / 1000);
    }
...//other part
free(pbDest);
free(pbSrc);
}
```

This "Test" function executes in 100ms without omp, but with it, it executes in 120ms.
So, i doubted the for clause using omp, but it's optimized correctly when use omp, from 50ms to 20ms
What is the problem.
I will be appreciated if you help me.

Comment: Enabling OpenMP might inhibit some of the optimisations. If I recall correctly, there was a similar question some time ago, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: I agree with @HristoIliev. If you really want to know, you will have to look at the assembly code generated by your compiler.

Comment: I agree with the above, and if you want more specific help, you might want to include `//other part' as well.

Comment: Other part does not have any relation with for clause. they are independent and further it's huge part to post here.